# The mathematical solution for the formation of infinite images in parallel mirrors is incorrect?

Tags: optics, reflection, mirror-symmetry

Textbooks and websites say that parallel mirrors form a $0^\circ$ angle between them and that is why the number of images formed is $(360^\circ/0)$ or infinite.

But I challenge this. There are two reasons of why this can not be true:

$ 1)~~$  A $0^\circ$ angle is formed when two lines/rays lie exactly over each other. In simple words, they intersect at every point. This contradictory to the fact that the mirrors are parallel.

$ 2)~~$ Even if we accept the $0^\circ$ angle, $(360^\circ/0)=$ undefined; not infinite There is a simple difference between being undefined and being infinite.

I am a class $9$ student, so please explain in simple terms...

Comment: Is your problem with the result or the Mathematical formalism? Bc you can easily show that the number of images is positive and arbitrarily large, which is the same as 'infinity', or in the, in the limit reaches infinity. You can simply let the first reflection be I_1, show that for every I_i there is I_{i+1} of the same size.

Comment: @xxx-69-swag-69-xxx I am a class 9 student. How am I supposed to prove that? Can you please explain that in an answer?

Comment: You are right to say that two parallel lines don't actually have 0 degrees between them, but, think about lines with angles approaching 0, those lines would be parallel with each other, we say it "approaches 0", and in fact since the angle between them is always positive, we can say 350/theta -> infinity, it would be undefined if we went to positive 0 on one side and negative zero on the other

Comment: @xxx-69-swag-69-xxx That is what I mean. The formulation in textbooks and websites is incorrect in this context.

Comment: this document seems to address your question, but I don't know to what rigor you want to go mathematically https://opentextbc.ca/universityphysicsv3openstax/chapter/images-formed-by-plane-mirrors/#:~:text=Two%20parallel%20mirrors%20can%20produce,only%20to%20identify%20the%20images.

Comment: you can try to think about the fact that for the graph 1/x^2 vs. 1/x, one of them approaches infinity at 0, and the other is undefined; you can think about that for a starting point

Comment: @xxx-69-swag-69-xxx that goes behind my level. Can you please explain it in an answer?

Answer (score 1):

This will be an explanation of the phenomena without the use of the intersecting angle of parallel mirrors.

Consider a set of parallel mirrors with an object in between them, the object creates a virtual image behind each of the mirrors respectively, let's call them $I_1$ and $I_2$. Now consider that $I_1$ and $I_2$ themselves have rays coming outwards towards the mirror which they are $\textbf{not}$ behind (i.e. towards the other mirror), and as result they each make 2 other images, lets call them $I_3$ and $I_4$. Notice that for 2 perfectly parallel mirrors, because they share a normal axis, all of the images we have placed so far are going to be on the same axis, that means we can draw a line through all of them.

Now we see a pattern forming; $I_3$ and $I_4$ will create images $I_5$ and $I_6$, etc. And this will go on growing forever, we can say the number of images approaches infinity.

Separate note: When mathematicians use "undefined" vs. "infinity", there is a subtle difference; since both are equally not numbers that you can be "equal to" in the strict sense, however they mean different things. For example imagine the following graphs: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/vnnzwnezzw  . Both functions are not defined at 0, however we can see that the blue graph approaches infinity from both sides, whereas the green graph goes to positive infinity on one side, and negative infinity on the other, so it doesn't really approach anything. So we can say that the blue graph approaches infinity as x approaches 0, but for the green graph we say it is undefined as x approaches 0. (This concept is called limits, it forms the basis of Calculus)

Comment: Thanks, It was actually that as a 9th grader I had a lot of difficulty understanding this "limits" thing.. But now as a high-school student I get it, and the study of vectors also cleared my doubts on this "$0$ angle" thing. Now that I re-go through your answer, I find it really good.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness  to the answer by xXx_69_SWAG_69_xXx ,  here [is a photo](https://skullsinthestars.com/2011/07/30/infinity-is-weird-even-in-infinity-mirrors/)  of real life parallel mirrors,

[image]

> First, a few words about the “infinity effect”.  As the picture above implies, to see an infinite number of images of an object one has to look at it in the mirror off-center: the cameraman in the photograph is standing behind and to the left of the woman.

The rest of the article may interest you.

Answer (score 1):

1. A 0⁰ angle is formed when two lines/rays lie exactly over each other. In simple words, they intersect at every point. This contradictory to the fact that the mirrors are parallel.

If you have line A and line B which are at angle phi, any pair of lines which are parallel to A and B are also at the same angle. So just because two coincident lines are at 0 angle to each other does not imply they are the only lines at that angle to each other.

Note that when you have two normal mirrors in the real world, they won't meet at a point, but there will be gap between their reflective surfaces (the 'silver' on the back of the glass is what reflects the light, so even if the glass is touching the reflective surfaces do not). If it's ok for those non-touching surfaces to be at an angle to each other, and not ok for other non-touching surfaces to be at an angle because the angle has decreased to zero, then I really can't see how to explain any further.

2. Even if we accept the 0⁰ angle, (360⁰/0)= undefined; not infinite There is a simple difference between being undefined and being infinite.

Yes, as a simple expression the value is undefined. Instead, consider changing the angle between the mirrors until it is zero. So mathematically we care about the limit of k/x as x tends to zero; this value increases indefinitely as x becomes infinitesimally small, so we can informally say the value is infinite.

Comment: @WebDevelopmentPro https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/bookI/propI29.html

Comment: The angle AGE and CHE are the same. Therefore the angle a line makes with one line and another line parallel to that line is the same. Therefore "a 0⁰ angle is formed when two lines/rays lie exactly over each other" directly implies "parallel [lines] form a 0∘ angle between them". Alternatively, any value other than zero would imply they are not parallel.

Comment: @WebDevelopmentPro You might as well ask how they even have an angle between them in the case where they are lying on top of each other. Euclid shows the angle is the same irrespective of which parallel line is chosen, you are happy that there is a zero angle if the lines are on top of each other, what's missing that means you can't make the logical step that therefore there are is a zero angle between parallel lines? Anything other than zero, the lines would meet at a single point.

Comment: @WebDevelopmentPro that is a rather unorthodox restriction to place on angles. What level of maths do you have?  In senior school you'll probably do/have done vector dot product and then the idea of angle won't require any positional constraint.

Comment: @WebDevelopmentPro whose definition is that? That is closer to the definition of a vertex, angles are more general, and extend to higher dimensions.

Comment: Soory for the fuss I made, because that was what I knew with my knowledge as a 9th-grader. Your answer, as I analyse it now is actaually good and helpful